# Replace all but last occurrences of a character in a string with pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

using Pandas to remove all but last period in a string like so:

```
s = pd.Series(['1.234.5','123.5','2.345.6','678.9'])
counts = s.str.count('\.')
target = counts==2
target
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

s = s[target].str.replace('\.','',1)
s
0    1234.5
2    2345.6
dtype: object
```

my desired output, however, is:

```
0    1234.5
1    123.5
2    2345.6
3    678.9
dtype: object
```

The replace command along with the mask target seem to be dropping the unreplaced values and I can't see how to remedy this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Regex-based with `str.replace`

This regex pattern with `str.replace` should do nicely.

```
s.str.replace(r'\.(?=.*?\.)', '')

0    1234.5
1     123.5
2    2345.6
3     678.9
dtype: object
```

The idea is that, as long as there are more characters to replace, keep replacing. Here's a breakdown of the regular expression used.

```
\.     # '.'
(?=    # positive lookahead
.*?    # match anything
\.     # look for '.'
)
```

---

### Fun with `np.vectorize`

If you want to do this using `count`, it isn't impossible, but it is a challenge. You can make this easier with `np.vectorize`. First, define a function,

```
def foo(r, c):
    return r.replace('.', '', c)
```

Vectorize it,

```
v = np.vectorize(foo)
```

Now, call the function `v`, passing `s` and the counts to replace.

```
pd.Series(v(s, s.str.count(r'\.') - 1))

0    1234.5
1     123.5
2    2345.6
3     678.9
dtype: object
```

Keep in mind that this is basically a glorified loop.

---

### Loopy/List Comprehension

The python equivalent of `vectorize` would be,

```
r = []
for x, y in zip(s, s.str.count(r'\.') - 1):
    r.append(x.replace('.', '', y))

pd.Series(r)

0    1234.5
1     123.5
2    2345.6
3     678.9
dtype: object
```

Or, using a list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([x.replace('.', '', y) for x, y in zip(s, s.str.count(r'\.') - 1)])

0    1234.5
1     123.5
2    2345.6
3     678.9
dtype: object
```

Comment: So this replaces any periods as long as another is matched ahead of it? I can accept in 3 minnutes haha, your too quick.

Comment: @seanysull Hmm, with `replace` and regex? Hmm, whatever the case, you need to know whether there is a character in front, so the lookahead cannot be avoided.

Comment: I mean without regex just using str.count and a mask etc

Comment: @seanysull I can be done but it will feel like going from London to NY through Moskow. You could count the dots in every entry (say `n`), and replace the first `n-1` instances of it with `''`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yep, that would basically be falling back to pure python at that point.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Great job as always!

Comment: Thanks guys that was an elnightening post and discussion

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the masked items and keep the rest untouched. Thats exactly what `Series.where` does, except it replaces the unmasked values so you need to negate the mask.

```
s.where(~target, s.str.replace('\.','',1))
```

Or you can make the changes in-place by assigning the masked values, this is probably cheaper but destructive.

```
s[target] = s[target].str.replace('\.','',1)
```